# How to send data with html tag in Postman body request?

Tags: http, curl, postman, httpclient, wysiwyg

I need to save data with html tag in Postman body request (raw/JSON) format via HTTP post method. When I tried it throws error as like the following image. How can I send data with html tag (What I see is what you get - WYSIWYG) in postman body?

[image]

Comment: Don't you need to encode the html? So that the ' in position 69 becomes &#39; rather than a ' which ends the "content" string prematurely?

Answer (score 1):

You could encode the html into a base64 string and pass the string in postman.This can later be decoded to the original html once the request body is received in the codebase.

For the encoding and decoding you can use `btoa` and `atob`.A reference on this can be found in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64)

An example of encoding the html string would look like this:

```
let htmlstring =`<html>
                <body>
                <p>This is test html</p>
                </body>
                </html>`
let htmlencodedString = btoa(htmlstring); // pass this htmlencodedString in the postman body
```

An example of decoding this would look like this:

```
let decodedString = atob(htmlencodedString); // this will give back the original html
```

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes `"` need escaping as `\"`
You can find and replace the value in your code editor. Like find all `"` and replace it with `\"`

**Example:**

```
"content": "<p><img class="img-responsive" src="the-url" alt="the alt" style="the styles"><p>"
```

should be

```
"content": "<p><img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"the-url\" alt=\"the alt\" style=\"the styles\"><p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no single quotes in JSON and there shouldn't be an ending comma ,

Enclose the value of content with double double quotes instead of single quotes and remove the comma after content value

Answer (score 0):

The JSON seems to be not formatted correctly. Did you try to replace unexpected sequences like the \r before you POST the JSON again?